# Find the uncertainty in position

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

The question says:

> A proton is accelerated to one tenth of the velocity of light. If it's velocity can be measured with a precision $\pm 1\%$. What must be its uncertainty in position?

Therefore,

$v=0.1 \times c =3\cdot 10^7\ \pu{m/s}\\
 \Delta(v)=\frac{1}{100}\\
 m= 1.6\cdot10^{-27}\ \pu{kg}$

Then I directly substituted these values into the formula:
$$\Delta(v)\cdot\Delta(\text{position})\cdot \text{mass}=\frac h{4\pi}$$

To get the uncertainty in position, however, the answer I got was approx. $3.5 \cdot 10^{-6}\ \pu{m}$ which is way too different from the correct answer:

> $0.5\cdot10^{-13}\ \pu{m}.$

Can anyone please explain me how to solve this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question tells you
\begin{aligned}
&&v&=3\cdot10^7\:\mathrm{m/s}\pm1\%\\
&&\Delta v &= |(v+1\%v) - (v-1\%v)|\\
\implies&&\Delta v &= \frac{2}{100}v\\
\therefore&&\Delta v&= 2\cdot3\cdot10^5\:\mathrm{m/s}
\end{aligned}

Hence
\begin{aligned}
&&\Delta x\cdot\Delta p &\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}\\
\implies&&\Delta x\cdot\Delta (v\cdot m) &\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}\\
\implies&&\Delta x&\geq \frac{\hbar}{2\cdot\Delta v\cdot m }\\
\therefore&&\Delta x &\gtrapprox\frac{1.05\cdot10^{−34}\:\mathrm{J\cdot s}}{2\cdot6\cdot10^5\:\mathrm{m/s}\cdot1.6\cdot10^{−27}\:\mathrm{kg}}\\
&&\Delta x&\gtrapprox5.5\cdot10^{-14}\:\mathrm{m}\\
\end{aligned}